# R programming: Carry forward a value in a column repeatedly based on a value in another column

Tags: r, function, data.table

In R, ideally data.table, I have the following dataset:

```
dt1 <- data.table(
  w0 = c(0, 0, 3, rep(0, 10)),
  x1 = c(0, 0, 1, rep(0, 10)))
```

And I would like to create one new variable x2 that carries forward the value in x1 based on the value in w0.

Something that works like this:

```
dt1[, x2 := function(x1, w0)]
```

Which then results into a variable that looks like this:

```
dt1[, x2 := c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, rep(0, 8))]
dt1
```

FYI: The "carried forward" variable x1 will not overlap with any next original value in x1.

EDIT (based on Greg's comment):
It's actually carrying forward a 1 in a dummy variable and then overwrite the consecutive 0s. The values of w0 = 0 can be ignored and w0 > 0 will only appear where x1 = 1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please define what it means to "carry forward" a value.  For instance, in the third row we have a `w0` of `3`, so presumably we overwrite `3` consecutive values with that value (`1`) of `x1`, starting in that very row.  But in the first row, we have a `w0` of `0`; so what does it mean to "carry forward" a value `0` times?  Is it any different than "carrying forward" a value `1` time?  Finally, when we "carry forward" a value (like `1` in the third row) multiple times (like `3` times), what happens to the overwritten values?  Do we "carry them forward" in their own turn, or do we ignore them?

Comment: More specifically, a `w0` of `1` is self explanatory: the `x1` value should appear `1` time, so it is essentially unmodified.  But by that logic, wouldn't `0` _remove_ the value?  Wouldn't a negative `w0` "carry it backward"?

Comment: You are right. I could have been more precise. It's actually carrying forward a 1 in a dummy variable and then overwrite the consecutive 0s. The values of w0 = 0 can be ignored and w0 > 0 will only appear where x1 = 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a small helper function to accomplish the same:

```
fn <- function(w,x){
  i1 <- w > 0
  x[sequence(w[i1], seq_along(w)[i1])] <- rep(x[i1], w[i1])
  x
}

dt1[,x2 := fn(w0,x1)][]
    w0 x1 x2
 1:  0  0  0
 2:  0  0  0
 3:  3  1  1
 4:  0  0  1
 5:  0  0  1
 6:  0  0  0
 7:  0  0  0
 8:  5  2  2  # New line added
 9:  0  0  2
10:  0  0  2
11:  0  0  2
12:  0  0  2
13:  0  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing this as a "reduction", simply because we don't know a priori how many `w0` will meet the condition, and we want to preserve what changes we can from previous rows.

```r
dt1[, x2new := Reduce(function(prev, ind) fifelse(.I %in% (ind + 0:2), x1[ind], prev),
                      which(w0 != 0), init = x1)]
dt1
#        w0    x1    x2 x2new
#     <num> <num> <num> <num>
#  1:     0     0     0     0
#  2:     0     0     0     0
#  3:     3     1     1     1
#  4:     0     0     1     1
#  5:     0     0     1     1
#  6:     0     0     0     0
#  7:     0     0     0     0
#  8:     0     0     0     0
#  9:     0     0     0     0
# 10:     0     0     0     0
# 11:     0     0     0     0
# 12:     0     0     0     0
# 13:     0     0     0     0
```

Quick walk-through:

- `which(.)` returns a list of indices, which, if empty, just passes `x1` (from `init=`) through unchanged;
- `.I` is all row numbers, so `ind+0:2` means "the non-zero row and two following it", and the use of `%in%` means we aren't concerned if `ind+2` is more than we have rows in the frame; using `fifelse`, if each row number is found in `ind + 0:2` then replace those rows with the single value of `x1[ind]`, otherwise we use the values returned by the previous call to the anon-func
- on the first call of the inner function, `prev` is the existing values from `x1` (because of `init=x1`), and `ind` is the row number of the first non-zero `w0`, which is 3` in this case;
- on the second call (if it were to happen), then `prev` is the set of values from the previous call to the anon-func, so within the `fifelse` if the rows are *not* to be affected, then we pass through the values as returned by that previous call;
- `prev` always means "return from the last call of the anon-func" except for the first time when it is filled by `init=`;
- `ind` always means (in this case) the next row number where `w0` is non-zero.

Notes:

- It's not perfectly clear to me if we should always use the pre-`Reduce` values of `x1` for repeating, or if we should be using `fifelse(..., prev[ind], prev)` instead
- if you're tempted (as I am) to define this `function(prev, ind)` *outside* the `Reduce` call and *outside* the `dt1[...]` enclosure,

  ```r
  fun <- function(prev, ind) fifelse(.I %in% (ind + 0:2), x1[ind], prev)
  dt1[, x2new := Reduce(fun, which(w0 != 0), init = x1)]
  # Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : object 'x1' not found
  ```

  the `x1` is not found. One workaround involves a touch of meta-programming:

  ```r
  fun <- function(DT) function(prev, ind) DT[, fifelse(.I %in% (ind + 0:2), x1[ind], prev)]
  dt1[, x2new := Reduce(fun(.SD), which(w0 != 0), init = x1)]
  ```

  where `fun(..)` returns a function, which is then used for finding `x1`.

  ***IF INSTEAD*** we should be using `fifelse(.., prev[ind], prev)`, then this problem goes away so long as we also replace `.I` with `seq_along(prev)` (which we can use anyway):

  ```r
  fun <- function(prev, ind) fifelse(seq_along(prev) %in% (ind + 0:2), prev[ind], prev)
  dt1[, x2new := Reduce(fun, which(w0 != 0), init = x1)]
  ```

For anybody else that is interested, this last form of `fun` works perfectly well in non-`data.table`:

```r
library(dplyr)
fun <- function(prev, ind) if_else(seq_along(prev) %in% (ind + 0:2), prev[ind], prev)
tibble(dt1) |>
  mutate(x2new = Reduce(fun, which(w0 != 0), init = x1))
```

we could even throw in `purrr::reduce` if you're loath to use base R :-)

Answer (score 2):

A plodder's alternative:

```
tmp <- dt1[w0>0, .(x2 = rep(x1, w0)), by=.I][, I := I + seq_len(.N)-1, by=I]
dt1[, x2 := x1][tmp$I, x2:=tmp$x2]

> dt1
       w0    x1    x2
    <num> <num> <num>
 1:     0     0     0
 2:     0     0     0
 3:     3     1     1
 4:     0     0     1
 5:     0     0     1
 6:     0     0     0
 7:     0     0     0
 8:     0     0     0
 9:     0     0     0
10:     0     0     0
11:     0     0     0
12:     0     0     0
13:     0     0     0
```

NB requires data.table 1.15.0 (for `by=.I`)

This just expands the relevant rows in a new table, creates a column for the row no. where they should go in the old table, and overwrites a clone of x1 at those rows.